# How to promote a Gerrit draft submission to a regular code-review submission

Tags: gerrit

A colleague sent me a Gerrrit code review "draft" (I suppose via "refs/drafts/master" instead of "refs/for/master") and then left on holiday. Without downloading the patch and submitting it myself, how can I promote his draft to a full regular code-review so I can approve it & submit it for merging?

I think [this is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29263238/1245420), but it's for git-review, not Gerrit. Also I'm interested in doing it from the Gerrit web GUI if at all possible. And I don't see a "Publish" button on my Gerrit web GUI for that draft. (And currently it doesn't say anything about merge conflicts, as long as I hurry....)

If I click on the "Patch Sets" link in the top right of the GUI, this is what I see:
[image: What I see when I click on "Patch Sets"]

In the top left it says "Change 58358 - Draft", and in the middle of the window it shows this:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the change owner can publish a draft patch set. Using the UI's cherry-pick option as described in other answers won't work because the cherry-pick implementation preserves the draft status on the new change or patch set.

As far as I know the only way to force the change into `NEW` state is to manually download the commit and push a new patch set using `refs/for/master` instead of `refs/drafts/master`.

Note that if you're not rebasing the change onto a new parent at the same time, you might need to slightly edit the commit message to make gerrit accept it.  Otherwise it'll reject with `no new changes`.

Answer (score 0):

If your colleague add you as reviewer, you can. You can cherry-pick this commit.

Click on **download** link at the right-top corner, and there are aliases for commands above.
But as you updated your question, you don't want to check out and manually push or cherry pick to master branch. You can use cherry-pick\merge button on ui, if you are confident in this mr, and it should be on master branch. Also you can publish this commit for other reviewers.

[image]

p.s. updated (you can cherry-pick, merge, publish via UI)

Comment: I updated my question with what I see in the top-right corner when I click on "Patch Sets". I don't see the aliases you mention....?

Comment: I'm sorry, give me a second, I'm writting new changes in my answer)

Comment: I clicked "Cherry Pick" and it asks me what branch, so I try to type "refs/for/master" but it doesn't like that (says "Code Review - Error, Branch refs/for/master does not exist"). If I just type "master", it accepts that and says I now have "Uploaded patch set 3", but in the top right it still says "Change 58358 - Draft", and it doesn't start a test build. Any more ideas?

Comment: Strange, do you see 'publish button' at the top over Owner, Reviewers titles, and do you have grants for +2?

Comment: I already +2'ed it. But I don't see a "Publish" button. The only instance of "Publish" is in the History section, in text that says "Patch Set 2: Published edit on patch set 1".

Comment: What submit type do you use ? You can check it 'Projects'->'General'

Comment: It says "Submit Type:  Cherry Pick"

Comment: try to enter in cherry-pick input, 'master:refs/for/master' without  quotes

Comment: Oh I was so hoping that would work, but:  "Branch master:refs/for/master does not exist."

Comment: Maybe it's helped refs/heads/master:refs/for/master, but I'm not sure.I know way to do this using console, but it isn't fitted for you. Also try follows: 1) Change your branch strategy to Merge if nessecary and submit this commit, 2) Have a look at your gerrit.config, in the branch section.

Comment: Open download at the top-right corner, copy checkout link, open git bash, paste it. Then you can 'git pull --rebase orign master', and 'git review master'. Then +2 by yourself, +1 from jenkins (if you use it) and then cherry-pick to master. (Because cherry pick is your gerrit strategy)

Comment: Well, thank you very much for your help, but that didn't work either. `$ git review master` results in `git: 'review' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`

Comment: If you feel that there's no value to this question & its answers, feel free to delete your answer. If both of the answers are deleted, I can then delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following procedure:

1) Go to the draft change page

2) Click on ***Cherry Pick*** button

3) Write "master" in the ***Cherry Pick to Branch*** field

4) Adjust the ***Cherry Pick Commit Message*** if needed

5) Click on ***Cherry Pick Change*** button

It'll be created a NEW CHANGE cherry-picked from the draft change. Go to the new change page and follow the regular Gerrit process (review, approve, submit). The original draft change can be abandoned or deleted.

Comment: Following those instructions the best I can (I'm not totally sure what the "draft change page" or "new change page" is), it added a history line that says "Uploaded patch set 4.", but that's all. It didn't start a build, it still says that I've +2'ed it, and it won't give me a submit button.

Comment: What's the Gerrit version? Have you clicked on the "Cherry Pick" button? You haven't clicked on "Rebase" button, have you?

Comment: So my people here tell me I can't do these things because I'm not the owner of the draft. In any case, this has turned out to be way too much trouble, and I'm handling it differently. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you weren't able to click on the "Cherry Pick" button you shouldn't have said that you had clicked on it.

Comment: Well, I can click on the "Cherry Pick" button. It then asks me what branch, and I typed "master", then clicked on the "Cherry Pick Change" button, then it adds a new patch set to the history, but it never converts the submission from "draft" to "Needs Code-Review", and never starts a build of it on Jenkins. It just keeps sitting there saying "Uploaded patch set X.".

Comment: Apparently we're using Gerrit Code Review version 2.11.3, if that's important. But by this point we've taken care of the problem by just submitting a new code review from a manual merge of the changes. Again, thank you for trying to help. I'm sorry it didn't work for me.

Comment: If you feel that there's no value to this question & its answers, feel free to delete your answer. If both of the answers are deleted, I can then delete the question.

Comment: The "Cherry Pick" button creates a NEW change. It doesn't create a new patchset in the change where you have clicked the button. Click on "My > Changes", you must see the changes you've created when you clicked on "Cherry Pick".

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira using the UI to cherry-pick a change to the same destination branch is effectively the same as doing a rebase.  IIRC the reason it doesn't publish the change is because the cherry-pick action preserves the draft status.

Comment: :-o I think this's totally unexpected behaviour. Thanks David.